# Kinetic color fill tween not working

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Im trying to change the color of the target node on mouse over and am currently using this code:

```
        layer.on('mouseenter', function(evt) {
            var shape = evt.targetNode;
            shape.moveTo(secondLayer);
            stage.draw()
            var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: shape,
                duration: 0.05,
                scaleX: 1.5,
                scaleY: 1.5,
                fillRed: 255,
                fillGreen: 102,
                fillBlue: 0,
            });
            tween.play()
        });

        secondLayer.on('mouseout', function(evt) {
            var shape = evt.targetNode;
            var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: shape,
                duration: 0.05,
                scaleX: 1,
                scaleY: 1,
                fillRed: 17,
                fillGreen: 17,
                fillBlue: 17,
                onFinish: function() {
                    shape.moveTo(layer);
                    layer.draw();
                }
            });
            tween.play();       
        });
```

The scale tween works fine however the color does not change at all. Not entirely sure what Im doing wrong.

Heres a jsfiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2C3Z/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'fill' attribute that you set for the triangle has priority over fillRed, fillGreen, and fillBlue... so you would also have to set the color with those RGB attributes when creating the triangle.

From the official [**change log**](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log):

> the color component API has changed a lot. fillR() has changed to
>   fillRed(), fillB() has changed to fillBlue(), etc. The same goes for
>   stroke and shadowColor components. The RGB() methods have been removed
>   because they have muddied up the API. i.e. fillRGB(), strokeRGB(), and
>   shadowColorRGB() have been removed. The components are now actual
>   attrs. the fill attr has priority over components. i.e. if you set
>   fill to 'blue' but you set the fillRed and fillGreen values, the fill
>   will resolve to blue.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2C3Z/6/) is a working jsfiddle of your code using the latest version of Kinetic JS. Note that I also had to change `evt.targetNode` to `evt.target`.

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense, would the same method work for say... fillRadialGradientColorStops:[],?

Comment: I do not think that fillRadialGradientColorStops can be used in a Tween yet... you'd have to try it out.